# Routing problem with calling a new method without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, form-for

I'm trying to put together a form_tag that edits several Shift objects.  I have the form built properly, and it's passing on the correct parameters.  I have verified that the parameters work with updating the objects correctly in the console.  However, when I click the submit button, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ShiftsController#update_individual
Couldn't find Shift without an ID
```

My route for the controller it is calling looks like this looks like this:

```
map.resources :shifts, :collection => { :update_individual => :put }
```

The method in ShiftsController is this:

```
def update_individual
  Shift.update(params[:shifts].keys, params[:shifts].values)
  flash[:notice] = "Schedule saved"
end
```

The relevant form parts are these:

```
<% form_tag( update_individual_shifts_path ) do %> 
  ... (fields for...)
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>  
<% end %>
```

Why is this not working?  If I browse to the url: "http://localhost:3000/shifts/update_individual/5" (or any number that corresponds to an existing shift), I get the proper error about having no parameters set, but when I pass parameters without an ID of some sort, it errors out.

How do I make it stop looking for an ID at the end of the URL?

Comment: how exactly is the `... (fields for...)` part?

Comment: It's no the simplest fields_for part, but it's this:
<% fields_for "shifts[]", Shift.find_or_create_by_date_and_time_and_club_id(d, "Early", c.id) do |s| %>
<%= s.collection_select :dealer_id, dealers, :id, :name %>
<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly, it turns out that I was able to fix this by a combination of renaming the method and passing a dummy variable.  Changes were to the lines:

form.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag( poop_individual_shifts_path ) do %>
```

routes.rb:

```
map.poop_individual_shifts "poop_shifts", :controller => 'shifts', :action => "poop_individual", :method => "put", :id => 4
map.resources :shifts
```

There I pass it an ID of 4 every time, it doesn't matter, it's not actually doing anything with the shift object it goes and grabs, it's just ... I don't know, a hack, I guess.

shifts_controller.rb:

```
def poop_individual
```

Comment: So the actual real reason for all that jazz was that I was using filter_resource_access in the method that was trying to force it to act RESTfully.  Oops.  If I changed the authorization a touch, then I didn't have to pass the dummy variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to tell the form tag helper you want to use PUT instead of POST

```
<% form_tag( update_individual_shifts_path, :method => :put) do %>
  ... fields ....
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nope, I'd tried that, and just retried it and still no luck.  Thank you, though.

Comment: And additionally, it is already getting called with PUT because that's how it's mapped in the routes.rb, as shown above.  =/

Comment: Oh really, that's a drag, maybe Shift.update doesn't like the format of params[:shifts] hash?

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird.  I have tried just copy/pasting the params[:shifts] hash from the trace when it dumps into console, and Shift.update handles the hash fine.  I spent a long time thinking that was the problem before realizing it was a routing issue...